# Browser Download status

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, mozilla

I am trying to build an application that could fetch me the status of a particular download from the browser like say if it is complete, the browser could trigger a signal or simply inform the user with a dialog box.

How should I proceed should I get into coding the browser plugins or it could be done using JS??

Comment: can't be done in "regular-@ss" JS

Comment: Anyway by which i can do it? Like if you could simply throw some light at how should i approach this problem

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `XMLHttpRequest`. As you download the data as binary you receive events indicating the status of the download. Once the download is complete you can get a link to your binary data using `URL.createObjectURL`.

Here is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", "image.png");
                request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
                request.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: "image/png"});
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    a.download = "image.png";
                    a.innerHTML = "File ready";
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                });
                request.send();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```